# PHP Mandrillapp send raw html with addGlobalMergeVar

Tags: php, html, email, mandrill

Is there any chance to send raw `html` eq. order table to `MandrillApp` template and get not `raw html`?

I have tried following code:

```
$itemTable = 'html table'
->addGlobalMergeVar('order_items_table_content', $itemTable);
```

My handlebars html template:

```
   {{ order_items_table_content }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using handlebars, use three `{` instead of two.

This will be escaped:

```
{{ my_html_value }}
```

This will not be escaped:

```
{{{ my_html_value }}}
```

More info: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582537-Using-Handlebars-for-Dynamic-Content